# On scroll increment value by '0.1'

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

What I want is to increment a value on the `trigger` by scroll by `0.1` using jQuery.

```
pval = 0
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   pval++
   pval = 0.+pval
   console.log(pval);
});
```

I know it's a wrong way but I tried many ways but it's not happening anyway.Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: `pval += 0.1` ?

Comment: @NathanP. can we use -ve values so that it will become +ve.?

Comment: I don't understand `-ve`

Comment: @NathanP. what I meant is that can we use  `-0.1` and increment it to `0.1`

Comment: `pval -= 0.1` or  `pval += 0.2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax is  `pval = 0.1 +pval` or you can shorten   with +=

```
var pval = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   pval += 0.1; //short for pval =  pval+ 0.1
   console.log(pval);
});
```

Comment: Can we use `00.1` value in this method, or is there any other way in which we can use the smallest number than `0.1`?

Comment: @JithinRajPR Isn't 00.1 same as 0.1(math) ?

Comment: ty am weak in math, Sorry for that,  can we use `-ve` values so that it will become `+ve`

Comment: @JithinRajPR `can we use -ve values so that it will become +ve` can you please explain that?